# feature with multiple id used for style

Tags: qgis, sld, gml

I have features with multiple themeID, for example, themeID=49 and themeID=53, and when I load them into qgis it shows attribute themeID=(2:49,53). The problem is that I use themeID in sld to choose what svg sign to add to it, and now I can't find a way to use this. It would nice to solve this with use of sld but to leave possibility if there is only one themeID (than it won't be in form of(1:49))

feature in gml

```
<app:poMember>
<app:po gml:id="point1">
    <app:idElement>1001914</app:idElement>
    <app:desc>null</app:desc>
    <app:status>1</app:status>
    <app:markPKO>602346</app:markPKO>
    <app:themeID>49</app:themeID>
    <app:themeID>53</app:themeID>
    <app:xPoint>4963127.35</app:xPoint>
    <app:yPoint>6436882.64</app:yPoint>
    <app:zPoint>0.0</app:zPoint>
    <app:geoTopoMember>
        <gml:Node gml:id="n2">
            <gml:pointProperty>
                <gml:Point gml:id="p1" srsDimension="2" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31276">
                    <gml:pos>4963127.35 6436882.64</gml:pos>
                </gml:Point>
            </gml:pointProperty>
        </gml:Node>
    </app:geoTopoMember>
</app:po>
```

sld that I use

```
<Rule><Name>DPoint</Name><Title>DPoint</Title><ogc:Filter> <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>themeID</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>49</ogc:Literal> </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo> </ogc:Filter> <PointSymbolizer><Graphic><ExternalGraphic><OnlineResource xlink:type="simple"   xlink:href="/DPoint.svg"/><Format>image/svg+xml</Format></ExternalGraphic><Size>16</Size> <Rotation>0</Rotation></Graphic></PointSymbolizer></Rule><Rule><Name>BPoint</Name><Title>BPoint</Title><ogc:Filter> <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo><ogc:PropertyName>themeID</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>53</ogc:Literal> </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo> </ogc:Filter> <PointSymbolizer><Graphic><ExternalGraphic><OnlineResource xlink:type="simple"    xlink:href="/BPoint.svg"/><Format>image/svg+xml</Format></ExternalGraphic><Size>16</Size> <Rotation>0</Rotation></Graphic></PointSymbolizer></Rule>
```